# Как на вордпресе сделать плавную прокрутку с переходом на другую страницу?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Плавная прокрутка должна быть только на главной странице, а все остальные переходы должны быть стандартными.

Использую такой плавный переход, но он работает только на главной странице:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#primary-menu li a').click( function(){ // ловим клик по ссылке с классом go_to
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); // возьмем содержимое атрибута href, должен быть селектором, т.е. например начинаться с # или .
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) { // проверим существование элемента чтобы избежать ошибки
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); // анимируем скроолинг к элементу scroll_el
        }
        // return false; // выключаем стандартное действие
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#primary-menu li a').click(function () { // ловим клик по ссылке с классом go_to
        if (window.location.href.split('#')[0] != $(this).attr('href').split('#')[0]) return; // выйти, если не текущая страница
        var scroll_el = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1]; // возьмем содержимое атрибута href, должен быть селектором, т.е. например начинаться с # или .
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) { // проверим существование элемента чтобы избежать ошибки
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top}, 500); // анимируем скроолинг к элементу scroll_el
        }
        // return false; // выключаем стандартное действие
    });
});
```

Comment: не работет, в адресной строке должно быть solar/#fifth-block, а оно пишет solar/feedback/#fifth-block
feedback это страница на которой я нижимаю пункт меню

Comment: еще пробывал исползовать .each()
изменяя URL на всех страницах кроме home
но у меня не получилось реализовать это
остановился на вот этом
     var bicackle = $('#primary-menu li a').attr("href");
     $.each($('#primary-menu li a'), function(i, item) {
         console.log(bicackle+item);

     })

Comment: тоже самое только плавный скролл пропал))

Comment: Ээх, вот так давать ответы без тестов. Обычно я так не делаю. Ок, к вечеру сделаю тест и исправлю.

Comment: ничего страшного, вернуть как было я всегда смогу)
тут главное найти решение, чтоб и переходило и скролило плавно

Comment: Исправил ответ. Работает на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/

Comment: о и у меня все работает, спасибо выручели